# jQuery: Add Infinite Inputs and Process Form Data

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I've got a form for a contact database where the user can click a plus symbol and add infinite number of phone entry fields, email fields, address fields. I've already found out how to do this from other questions answered.

Now I need to know how to process that data. Each field which can be added infinitely has the same name. I was thinking these would be added to an array in which I could use a for or .each and loop through it.

One last thing is that I was sending this information through jQuery Ajax to a PHP page which would process all the data. I'm much more skilled in PHP than I am in jQuery, but jQuery is useful for not having to refresh a page, obviously. My question is is this bad practice? It seems to be a little slower. I know I could error check and process the data in js then send the processed data to a PHP page to be input in a database but I'm worried on how much harder it is to error check with js.

Comment: Which exactly is the bit you don't know how  to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding form elements, note that if you add square brackets to the end of the name, the posted data will be structured as an array-like object:

```
<input type="text" name="extrainput[]"/>
```

You can then iterate over the results and process user input.

So for example if you needed to have an indefinite number of textboxes for the user to enter his languages, you would use:

```
$('#addbutton').click(function(){
    $('#myform').append('<input type="text" name="languages[]"/>')
});
```

where `addbutton` is the id of the button the user would click to add another input.

To iterate over these form elements, you can use:

```
$('[name="languages[]"]').each(...)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I understand that you can do that but how do you process that in jQuery?

Comment: how are you creating the fields now?

Comment: @Asad I already have a way to create inputs. I'm using the exact same thing but without the []. What I'm asking is how do you process all the languages[] in jQuery. Like how do I get there values and store them?

Comment: @TylerDusty Where do you want to store them? I mean they're there in your page, if you want to iterate over them use `$('[name="languages[]"]').each(...)`

Comment: @Asad That's pretty much what I was asking for. I didn't really know how to iterate over them. I guess its pretty common knowledge and that's why in all the questions I looked over I couldn't find that part of code. Also I didn't think it was that easy.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to approach it, both have a similar result in PHP

Row 1

```
<input type="text" name="fullname[]" />
<input type="text" name="telephone[]" />
```

Row 2

```
<input type="text" name="fullname[]" />
<input type="text" name="telephone[]" />
```

Etc

$_POST will have an array of values whose indexes show which row they belong  to

Row 1

```
<input type="text" name="row[1][fullname]" />
<input type="text" name="row[1][telephone]" />
```

Row 2

```
<input type="text" name="row[2][fullname]" />
<input type="text" name="row[2][telephone]" />
```

$_POST will have an array per row

Comment: No idea why someone would downvote, but if I used `phone[]` in the name field then in PHP would `foreach($_POST('phone') as $p){//do something for each}` work?

Comment: It's since become apparent the person asking the question knows this part of the process and the question was about jquery. Next time - check the tags!

Comment: My next question to this would be how do you send a lot of form data (in this case possibly infinite) over Jquery Ajax to a PHP page? I've seen adding all the form data to a FormData obj but that wasn't really explained too well.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use 
`jQuery(yourDiv).data('mydata', anyObject);`
and then iterate

```
jQuery(selector of your divs).each(function(item){
    var obj = jQuery(item).data('mydata');
    // do anything you want here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array as name in html :

```
var i = 0;
$('.add').click(function(){
   var newE = $('<input/>').attr({type:'text',name:'data[]',value:i,'class':'inputs'});
   $('.myform').append(newE).hide().fadeIn('1000');
});
```

and for sending with ajax :

```
var data = {};
$.each($('.inputs'),function(i,val){
      data[i] = $(val).val();
});
callajaxfunction(data);
```

and then you can get this array with php :

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value){
   echo $key.':'.$value.'<br>';
}
```