# Form submissions: How to submit a list of dynamic multipart data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've got an HTML form that has some static fields and some fields that are dynamically added with javascript. It looks sort of like this

```
StaticField1: [textfield]
StaticField2: [textfield]

DynamicSet1: [textfield1.1] [textfield1.2]
DynamicSet2: [textfield2.1] [textfield2.2] [add_another_button]
...
```

Forgive the formatting. Basically, the idea is that a user clicks the "add-more-button" and a new set of fields is dynamically added to the form. I want to piece each set together in a single data structure on the server side. I can be crafty with how i name each of these fields and piece them back together manually, but that seems like a lot of effort :S. Is there another way to do this?

A general solution is perfect, but if there are any solutions specific to google appengine (python 2.7) and jquery that would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545504/jquery-add-infinite-inputs-and-process-form-data